# How to update core of application written by ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, content-management-system, auto-update

I'm making a new CMS from scratch in ASP.NET MVC. I need to add a self-update feature to CMS, so customers CMS get updates automatically whenever updates are available.

Assume a new update are available in a URL in a zip file. how can I download that zip file, extract it and replace it with the current ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: look into hosting your own nuget feed

Comment: so can customers update CMS with one click?

Comment: Is my problem can be solve multi-tenancy architecture?

Comment: You should read up on continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD)

Comment: Can download new bin and cshtml files remotely and place in client's hosts?

Comment: I solved the problem with a simple windows service that checks a URL to know if there's a new version of the product. If there's a new version, the windows service downloads a new version, do a backup from both application and database, and replaces the new version with the existing instance.